# Manually select peaks on a plot with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cursor, signal-processing

I am finding and plotting local maximas and minimas on a waveform with the function `findpeaks`. I would like to be able to select some of those peaks with a pointer directly from the plot and get the coordinates into the workspace.

Is that possible?

[image]

Here is a subset of an example dataset:

```
data = [-4.89540984473946e-06   -4.89046450287593e-06   -4.88283149336408e-06   -4.87095198116254e-06   -4.90712807029133e-06   -4.91927636347547e-06   -4.84407526018980e-06   -4.87589730823133e-06   -4.92470545237800e-06   -4.84429026519065e-06   -4.94884075275366e-06   -4.97668505593799e-06   -5.05091858731457e-06   -4.91637367843710e-06   -4.84267768702634e-06   -4.89191584860588e-06   -4.84660167647784e-06   -4.83337832656191e-06   -4.79032179995216e-06   -4.76624025231771e-06   -4.75887604778215e-06   -4.70856280330800e-06   -4.64964899691363e-06   -4.72963414438675e-06   -4.83950621114218e-06   -4.81381203536647e-06   -4.83251825696249e-06   -4.87320964430400e-06   -4.90336533160774e-06   -4.83783986967173e-06   -4.80376018565747e-06   -4.74447010720748e-06   -4.84961187054251e-06   -4.83536719945138e-06   -4.79919111834559e-06   -4.85611601862430e-06   -4.82606784644511e-06   -4.85471844872184e-06   -4.84386025701412e-06   -4.81515589140679e-06   -4.83353956282112e-06   -4.88793805514151e-06   -4.79279444702247e-06   -4.81897238803632e-06   -4.80263134571406e-06   -4.89245337024318e-06   -4.87165078787927e-06   -4.71388435646062e-06   -4.79182688643761e-06   -4.86353400235825e-06   -4.90288153698267e-06   -4.88181018900206e-06   -4.90814939463545e-06   -5.02565445022868e-06   -4.97270728327852e-06   -4.89395845050979e-06   -4.89019572804071e-06   -5.00581942056473e-06   -4.85815866007998e-06   -4.87890749444223e-06   -5.05392877098134e-06   -4.96442924133893e-06   -5.00549688200667e-06   -4.98668317977521e-06   -4.92502796151073e-06   -4.95034584308071e-06   -4.96141905730884e-06   -5.12907611359824e-06   -5.13993428270170e-06   -5.07462383072134e-06   -5.01700012945037e-06   -4.97609373883257e-06   -4.94351913722961e-06   -4.94255157997661e-06   -4.98587686360239e-06   -5.00968963210843e-06   -5.02554690501322e-06   -4.95346351631875e-06   -4.92153396677935e-06   -4.94884073137851e-06   -5.04333930187227e-06   -5.02522438757406e-06   -5.03941530333772e-06   -5.15149128554495e-06   -5.05236989188090e-06   -5.03366368296826e-06   -4.94265906728271e-06   -4.94975453582840e-06   -4.97340605765111e-06   -4.97690002973954e-06   -4.95776378585822e-06   -5.01318362006572e-06   -5.06478693414940e-06   -5.01995653541482e-06   -4.99791762200221e-06   -4.87826241180049e-06   -4.88250895410629e-06   -4.81209190921077e-06   -4.91621236220338e-06   -4.93239215982718e-06   -4.93792876456361e-06   -4.92712431672434e-06   -4.91895378603758e-06   -4.89820494557392e-06   -4.75527449565399e-06   -4.80870541294211e-06   -4.91949131649655e-06   -4.82714288810490e-06   -4.80058867327714e-06   -4.77408822193145e-06   -4.83574342467004e-06   -4.97727628837568e-06   -4.88003626339490e-06   -4.81934860759687e-06   -4.84611783428869e-06   -4.83192693662324e-06   -4.83101311610351e-06   -4.81993989876836e-06   -4.82601401869105e-06   -4.88035875610688e-06   -4.86423272630262e-06   -5.01286106570465e-06   -4.96292411288641e-06   -5.10537080127033e-06   -5.08919099820762e-06   -4.95163586368386e-06   -4.97227720195358e-06   -5.05339117694178e-06   -5.19503154703270e-06   -5.23636796094566e-06   -5.20373960447927e-06   -5.14745972271145e-06   -5.07161360140476e-06   -5.09994166445759e-06   -5.08150423089344e-06   -5.13251627052468e-06   -5.09445880665652e-06   -5.07473128332313e-06   -5.05581009966274e-06   -5.03672760927253e-06   -5.02543936932230e-06   -5.03285734881196e-06   -5.01302231887177e-06   -4.99770257519616e-06   -5.00458300346133e-06   -4.98372665851392e-06   -5.03651257822457e-06   -5.02414929072324e-06   -5.07596763603182e-06   -5.02108534123367e-06   -5.07489254669347e-06   -5.03033093518173e-06   -5.02855705432535e-06   -4.94325033413489e-06   -4.96249408236197e-06   -5.04129663718886e-06   -5.03183602180999e-06   -5.13036612636593e-06   -5.00716318699453e-06   -5.11418632652828e-06   -4.90406407090556e-06   -4.91072949082945e-06   -4.99426235774332e-06   -4.94765810874763e-06   -4.89868871329783e-06   -4.85590093201640e-06   -4.84278510314675e-06   -4.87487593151054e-06   -4.82219753090326e-06   -4.93034948804728e-06   -4.93868128118638e-06   -4.94325032124572e-06   -4.91293336390327e-06   -4.83418454545091e-06   -4.85514840665468e-06   -4.88132633107078e-06   -4.73936344658863e-06   -4.89798991183953e-06   -4.91674987033445e-06   -4.91099825512483e-06   -4.90481661159291e-06   -4.75065167397842e-06   -4.73081662246593e-06   -4.83106683653475e-06   -4.81902605804528e-06   -4.72286113134670e-06   -4.68061089959087e-06   -4.71307799071485e-06   -4.66426985378300e-06   -4.60019573139779e-06   -4.51252383793892e-06   -4.51204005491146e-06   -4.54912995301628e-06   -4.55810677145764e-06   -4.46866099529538e-06   -4.58896123793896e-06   -4.59310026040807e-06   -4.58202705111776e-06   -4.48430326328582e-06   -4.48795850933213e-06   -4.51924300905173e-06   -4.48543207246916e-06   -4.46855349494860e-06   -4.55337646172091e-06   -4.44345063281763e-06   -4.57154513493103e-06   -4.59385281489407e-06   -4.41711142485936e-06   -4.53913178401176e-06   -4.55606412110996e-06   -4.46264060897575e-06   -4.42463692084076e-06   -4.52155441407285e-06   -4.50677221940636e-06   -4.48634589207169e-06   -4.59396031491354e-06   -4.64728375852222e-06   -4.63664057022768e-06   -4.59965820617443e-06   -4.64911136961635e-06   -4.65884073472609e-06   -4.70695008507957e-06   -4.75586573646044e-06   -4.73178420321849e-06   -4.75801590401412e-06   -4.60471101137253e-06   -4.57471658105903e-06   -4.58584353491208e-06   -4.62363222795283e-06   -4.58793992938515e-06   -4.55482781015275e-06   -4.68437364815221e-06   -4.65249784756566e-06   -4.57933937481562e-06   -4.62631990328050e-06   -4.62089081158290e-06   -4.57917812541947e-06   -4.51225507656684e-06   -4.55477405258585e-06   -4.53311141783991e-06   -4.54939872432026e-06   -4.55117257965666e-06   -4.52789733425270e-06   -4.50650345378238e-06   -4.47903543044462e-06   -4.48312069612006e-06   -4.51419020129353e-06   -4.50145062688468e-06   -4.52735977698723e-06   -4.54450714032921e-06   -4.55117256252312e-06   -4.46608084509033e-06   -4.53407896158256e-06   -4.45140614557067e-06   -4.41920781351070e-06   -4.52881111872715e-06   -4.44624582148976e-06   -4.45909289459186e-06   -4.46274812107349e-06   -4.45748027280859e-06   -4.50951361740786e-06   -4.46887600458167e-06   -4.50902983974733e-06   -4.47457387229324e-06   -4.42200300467295e-06   -4.43549511692057e-06   -4.37695759401414e-06   -4.38319299076052e-06   -4.39695388751217e-06   -4.56692232078024e-06   -4.43619390131638e-06   -4.48392698684545e-06   -4.48269064668583e-06   -4.49526895605598e-06   -4.40947842813550e-06   -4.40765081368960e-06   -4.33094463147224e-06   -4.39802895440372e-06   -4.48215311323093e-06   -4.44398817350220e-06   -4.42307806797564e-06   -4.38330048298545e-06   -4.45748025906533e-06   -4.51983429633548e-06   -4.44973978296766e-06   -4.46274812303772e-06   -4.36239041550375e-06   -4.35497242302094e-06   -4.24794928477930e-06   -4.29444601665229e-06   -4.36255164763265e-06   -4.43114106994723e-06   -4.39652385759326e-06   -4.43802152606982e-06   -4.36142284958266e-06   -4.32116148894134e-06   -4.22204010180950e-06   -4.20666662863045e-06   -4.33357855390536e-06   -4.37615130510219e-06   -4.25902249968437e-06   -4.16731909488875e-06   -4.29810127026078e-06   -4.30869069847499e-06   -4.21639599654153e-06   -4.34551183219518e-06   -4.27622361239748e-06   -4.32411793285627e-06   -4.33782507529094e-06   -4.35932646891537e-06   -4.35491868199967e-06   -4.42931346065645e-06   -4.46446822094393e-06   -4.42098166754579e-06   -4.37857017732590e-06   -4.38722450174974e-06   -4.40017908708695e-06   -4.43764524852276e-06   -4.39534127545859e-06   -4.44006415615985e-06   -4.46984357275167e-06   -4.45694274459542e-06   -4.52381204489461e-06   -4.59718551829175e-06   -4.64292971925335e-06   -4.59562668122636e-06   -4.55998814171054e-06   -4.69238290131149e-06   -4.68259978578968e-06   -4.78618271604811e-06   -4.74554508911485e-06   -4.77306687647779e-06   -4.82902422748630e-06   -4.74022349874821e-06   -4.78967667659056e-06   -4.68560999623238e-06   -4.70399367174356e-06   -4.83488333484937e-06   -4.81424200588459e-06   -4.80553395017146e-06   -4.82827164485003e-06   -4.89798988689285e-06   -4.90750427683425e-06   -4.91562106073226e-06   -4.85041811053271e-06   -4.83198067332453e-06   -4.90702049436914e-06   -5.01140971443911e-06   -4.95115207847818e-06   -4.96695560075888e-06   -4.95894634250918e-06   -4.97442733132394e-06   -5.00146533478908e-06   -4.98619934294484e-06   -5.10123174293496e-06   -5.14579337049380e-06   -5.02968589389739e-06   -5.10698337504644e-06   -5.14235315096857e-06   -5.13294629440792e-06   -5.12536706933419e-06   -5.11187493758741e-06   -5.04264047326268e-06   -5.07591387573231e-06   -5.11225121369745e-06   -5.12934481360250e-06   -5.14127807813422e-06   -5.04500564269106e-06   -5.12020673493844e-06   -5.23507787622358e-06   -5.16761728731260e-06   -5.12241062730512e-06   -5.10370441798274e-06   -5.13896668771534e-06   -5.16347825893636e-06   -5.25781558024835e-06   -5.26351346598172e-06   -5.16976743555304e-06   -5.14740596681149e-06   -5.14332071497995e-06   -5.20433089563993e-06   -5.13348383832941e-06   -5.21475907516790e-06   -5.27114645029502e-06   -5.29974328192358e-06   -5.29243281497749e-06   -5.18336704101590e-06   -5.18395833370644e-06   -5.19659038991682e-06   -5.22938000548113e-06   -5.15821043730756e-06   -5.18094815047183e-06   -5.27109269003538e-06   -5.21121133937498e-06   -5.15466270877798e-06   -5.22427343410753e-06   -5.13552647587313e-06   -5.09585642010333e-06   -5.02425678371832e-06   -5.08773962439909e-06   -5.11273501095427e-06   -5.09085734648637e-06   -5.13472017070403e-06   -5.11026234651260e-06   -4.93830501777556e-06   -4.90132261051010e-06   -4.98695189641788e-06   -5.11074611982211e-06   -5.12391570943425e-06   -4.99458489423704e-06   -4.95819380936770e-06   -4.89487222615777e-06   -4.84273136321247e-06   -4.92911319316957e-06   -4.97044959434856e-06   -5.06478691361076e-06   -4.95066831680678e-06   -4.95932263243045e-06   -4.89304460217765e-06   -4.90718177731852e-06   -4.95448481663433e-06   -4.98480176798481e-06   -5.01522623575681e-06   -4.96674060947798e-06   -4.89132449101996e-06   -4.88998066549326e-06   -4.97308351915836e-06   -4.98173782509740e-06   -4.94244403930944e-06   -4.86971560265590e-06   -5.02646069264862e-06   -5.00512057189556e-06   -5.05828274361789e-06   -5.01850518922777e-06   -4.98619935583612e-06   -5.01823641196971e-06   -4.95486109073768e-06   -4.96496672723791e-06   -4.95136708846810e-06   -5.01393612496185e-06   -5.11461636982289e-06   -5.14229939099664e-06   -5.16627342760414e-06   -5.13149494555811e-06   -5.22309085185195e-06   -5.20900744562811e-06   -5.10085549026536e-06   -5.12719468332557e-06   -5.16960616961794e-06   -5.22631606661904e-06   -5.17938930219621e-06   -5.22362839337094e-06   -5.26270715341434e-06   -5.28920762120520e-06   -5.28479983942088e-06   -5.34172474221797e-06   -5.22717612139269e-06   -5.20314832822807e-06   -5.24013070017282e-06   -5.43799718960251e-06   -5.43412693551289e-06   -5.45858475339959e-06   -5.50492025712232e-06   -5.48481646690506e-06   -5.42197866239572e-06   -5.42353752087345e-06   -5.43600832255097e-06   -5.52658289608058e-06   -5.51690727283137e-06   -5.41617329020160e-06   -5.41515197559490e-06   -5.52873305121873e-06   -5.53002313061791e-06   -5.42267746815339e-06   -5.33978963365147e-06   -5.44245873969728e-06   -5.45138180379219e-06   -5.49997492391736e-06   -5.48589151941974e-06   -5.50212507459059e-06   -5.49427706897414e-06   -5.41294808602362e-06   -5.47320572027297e-06   -5.53480718404686e-06   -5.57582106855960e-06   -5.51615472885835e-06   -5.47497957994393e-06   -5.58028260548941e-06   -5.59968761060948e-06   -5.48556900608788e-06   -5.45277938759969e-06   -5.58205645126603e-06   -5.60253653948927e-06   -5.66655691880590e-06   -5.73536135294201e-06   -5.62634933045323e-06   -5.66661064980999e-06   -5.71434373612397e-06   -5.76299062783483e-06   -5.71434373874723e-06   -5.70235670500012e-06   -5.50787667035274e-06   -5.46277751425852e-06   -5.43772839801462e-06   -5.49228815542689e-06   -5.61296470280075e-06   -5.68424178318152e-06   -5.70343176567384e-06   -5.70740951854130e-06   -5.64140027568978e-06   -5.64983958052105e-06   -5.54808427913237e-06   -5.58888314248457e-06   -5.69805642928122e-06   -5.63000454665461e-06   -5.66021399927151e-06   -5.75186364900393e-06   -5.59538731929230e-06   -5.57603607368943e-06   -5.51475710522887e-06   -5.46992672665820e-06   -5.42203239891019e-06   -5.54211762875043e-06   -5.56582290556767e-06   -5.41988225341455e-06   -5.40923906089805e-06   -5.47949483705825e-06   -5.51271447930229e-06   -5.55770612593648e-06   -5.55362086525713e-06   -5.42934286632973e-06   -5.40214361208860e-06   -5.48917046629352e-06   -5.50965055040005e-06   -5.47433453479784e-06   -5.47707595957126e-06   -5.49132061153509e-06   -5.40993786088237e-06   -5.41332432036094e-06   -5.29431416253087e-06   -5.27603798331231e-06   -5.29839942415794e-06   -5.34156346257886e-06   -5.24228081786113e-06   -5.42654768330477e-06   -5.34215474508166e-06   -5.41687204660465e-06   -5.47632337748322e-06   -5.48153746558058e-06   -5.45068299949198e-06   -5.39633825335762e-06   -5.38612509951272e-06   -5.35844205100384e-06   -5.32538366340842e-06   -5.41020661741338e-06   -5.46353006578526e-06   -5.39762831694138e-06   -5.43170802282690e-06   -5.48750412420699e-06   -5.58592669808638e-06   -5.47266815048819e-06   -5.48422516113002e-06   -5.55517972822541e-06   -5.60221399654449e-06   -5.53330205540489e-06   -5.61941509905129e-06   -5.63973390081090e-06   -5.64484049731144e-06   -5.50051243706660e-06   -5.51163939563723e-06   -5.64742063527922e-06   -5.67209347237735e-06   -5.65935390806408e-06   -5.69321858724285e-06   -5.75600263829014e-06   -5.60199897405416e-06   -5.67392109252045e-06   -5.72627696597894e-06   -5.73917781511763e-06   -5.60646052156519e-06   -5.66037523413921e-06   -5.78691089727002e-06   -5.87200260678621e-06   -5.91328528246058e-06   -5.87151883828506e-06   -5.83856795714906e-06   -5.92817497437017e-06   -5.93548546080599e-06   -5.87463653247661e-06   -5.95171899243511e-06   -5.90527599552075e-06   -5.89038629121416e-06   -6.00176343514282e-06   -6.02229725693547e-06   -5.94650491219471e-06   -5.89452530534357e-06   -5.97262907333676e-06   -6.02057716567032e-06   -6.04498124095891e-06   -6.03208041594050e-06   -5.94682742660133e-06   -5.94021573897517e-06   -5.93887191530283e-06   -5.94102205038252e-06   -6.02122223213133e-06   -6.04460497129116e-06   -5.98079960094166e-06   -5.98638996177472e-06   -5.97160775038871e-06   -5.93978570037840e-06   -5.92365965538281e-06   -5.99300163095193e-06   -5.98380978432889e-06   -5.92790620375100e-06   -5.99461424769442e-06   -5.93419534918941e-06   -6.02165222926862e-06   -6.01299793575300e-06   -5.93811936362023e-06   -5.90828615975766e-06   -5.93360404113511e-06   -6.02901645418901e-06   -6.03584313832001e-06   -5.93795810062678e-06   -5.98472359793705e-06   -5.96961887017841e-06   -5.88667726268544e-06   -5.80368192148849e-06   -5.96730746492287e-06   -5.93822686062853e-06   -5.87082001436852e-06   -5.76428063705576e-06   -5.87092750557774e-06   -5.89780422693046e-06   -5.87452896794551e-06   -5.84560961592563e-06   -5.86383203687022e-06   -5.86883110040176e-06   -5.79900536909068e-06   -5.62871440880852e-06   -5.70730194727375e-06   -5.75465876148963e-06   -5.74019908689073e-06   -5.68365044479493e-06   -5.67375979188971e-06   -5.55292201665917e-06   -5.51669217414419e-06   -5.55990995613614e-06   -5.52545400363319e-06   -5.62414535693739e-06   -5.63699243407591e-06   -5.61366342725965e-06   -5.52647532400086e-06   -5.56791923235924e-06   -5.47643083322858e-06   -5.51421952363263e-06   -5.57850864807533e-06   -5.47385065725829e-06   -5.43380433448031e-06   -5.39440303078793e-06   -5.41144287840893e-06   -5.38660877189569e-06   -5.41380802976399e-06   -5.48384879665080e-06   -5.41638820914534e-06   -5.38671629078859e-06   -5.40730386648816e-06   -5.30447349745795e-06   -5.43719078711484e-06   -5.51502580678293e-06   -5.48771904289687e-06   -5.53082931059948e-06   -5.46616389569207e-06   -5.40246604300234e-06   -5.37757819159447e-06   -5.40472368411455e-06   -5.45261803233513e-06   -5.50153368259830e-06   -5.53996739725791e-06   -5.51868103201207e-06   -5.48573016045100e-06   -5.49051420912711e-06   -5.51776721149034e-06   -5.44364119736049e-06   -5.49637334843401e-06   -5.53265693099902e-06   -5.38429736696079e-06   -5.44557630521909e-06   -5.41886085768137e-06   -5.38236222899405e-06   -5.54227879254047e-06   -5.46600263042054e-06   -5.33393037886201e-06   -5.38112591902652e-06   -5.53620465056360e-06   -5.53953737157883e-06   -5.60194514620983e-06   -5.62382279330292e-06   -5.52174497885962e-06   -5.51626211712965e-06   -5.53529083301262e-06   -5.63322963991197e-06   -5.54071991641543e-06   -5.58560406969271e-06   -5.63355217003026e-06   -5.68746687557798e-06   -5.72557809683548e-06   -5.74681070721292e-06   -5.64758181411515e-06   -5.58587283921792e-06   -5.59103316279369e-06   -5.59452712927172e-06   -5.60603037701969e-06   -5.71982645180166e-06   -5.76116286029805e-06   -5.56189878136957e-06   -5.51217684179510e-06   -5.60495531357065e-06   -5.54496644009520e-06   -5.48212863528228e-06   -5.50255496359689e-06   -5.54034364085478e-06   -5.45089788056670e-06   -5.40579871851138e-06   -5.38687753161319e-06   -5.41493683351232e-06   -5.37870699108488e-06   -5.41278667278869e-06   -5.41622688537485e-06   -5.40789511160194e-06   -5.40655128493490e-06   -5.28942248836993e-06   -5.28802488676584e-06   -5.38639371567867e-06   -5.32817871775360e-06   -5.37413793933207e-06   -5.49314810275190e-06   -5.60027874194595e-06   -5.51416569761865e-06   -5.49717959556793e-06   -5.49830841283345e-06   -5.52615270040722e-06   -5.47696830588858e-06   -5.47578572834985e-06   -5.52685149816945e-06   -5.52830283605021e-06   -5.48046225678601e-06   -5.50406003821635e-06   -5.48132234015409e-06   -5.47626951443504e-06   -5.49879219744894e-06   -5.51094047971048e-06   -5.46111102002430e-06   -5.40735755043941e-06   -5.34258462523545e-06   -5.37618055541577e-06   -5.31216017130203e-06   -5.33242524377630e-06   -5.31866435529325e-06   -5.29350775144891e-06   -5.23615280476852e-06   -5.22927234832385e-06   -5.16546699306750e-06   -5.05258472615354e-06   -5.11477747260567e-06   -5.05064959284116e-06   -5.04629556415876e-06   -4.99367090607053e-06   -4.99195080382841e-06   -5.00802308521128e-06   -4.94948558628495e-06   -4.90954674975368e-06   -5.04043642972469e-06   -5.02199898248048e-06   -5.00205645122296e-06   -5.17057355603148e-06   -5.03188963268342e-06   -5.00490538855339e-06   -4.96502032574281e-06   -4.97372837921458e-06   -4.95727982838450e-06   -4.93362828929532e-06   -4.97888870877928e-06   -5.00555042632034e-06   -4.97792113779404e-06   -4.89793598556043e-06   -4.94717416063484e-06   -5.00538917849674e-06   -4.92266259450500e-06   -4.92148001217477e-06   -4.96383773060392e-06   -4.84783775858551e-06   -4.78327985632729e-06   -4.84267743862670e-06   -4.88928168484461e-06   -4.91642718735649e-06   -4.74748006614417e-06   -4.84181737893114e-06   -4.81752080739420e-06   -4.67174142447862e-06   -4.73726688321590e-06   -4.79139662959378e-06   -4.82171360391750e-06   -4.83284057642901e-06   -4.84751526526804e-06   -4.87423073209731e-06   -4.85805093797883e-06   -4.75419925031973e-06   -4.85901850328573e-06   -4.91680347130784e-06   -4.88702405057843e-06   -5.09010462494739e-06   -5.22943359438442e-06   -5.19755778815083e-06   -5.12165789218515e-06   -5.06349664591349e-06   -5.07892390279114e-06   -5.15794149654972e-06   -5.15084602720091e-06   -5.21733906443099e-06   -5.26329827367789e-06   -5.24475333813980e-06   -5.24991366982997e-06   -5.27507028143886e-06   -5.25593406205597e-06   -5.38698498660486e-06   -5.33828435751415e-06   -5.36064579501660e-06   -5.28625100220416e-06   -5.30909623196335e-06   -5.36155962445233e-06   -5.37048268528820e-06   -5.39983206064599e-06   -5.35403411039474e-06   -5.39950954893382e-06   -5.47508692543759e-06   -5.37967452378114e-06   -5.46170229426191e-06   -5.52717401615887e-06   -5.56716659578404e-06   -5.45777829252873e-06   -5.36446228660623e-06   -5.38768378185095e-06   -5.39311288226295e-06   -5.36634366191503e-06   -5.36182836931477e-06   -5.31124636241299e-06   -5.34328344474290e-06   -5.42127969859080e-06   -5.42832139675068e-06   -5.35763559895865e-06   -5.33210270749199e-06   -5.35575422844336e-06   -5.29528158619511e-06   -5.31769678958663e-06   -5.34602484810977e-06   -5.30888121573785e-06   -5.29893681843310e-06   -5.19788030754737e-06   -5.22104804554750e-06   -5.12880710066183e-06   -5.09795261449947e-06   -5.16810087623664e-06   -5.20223431856199e-06   -5.09064212910719e-06   -5.02087015275136e-06   -4.96851428050948e-06   -4.85364312718931e-06   -4.83300179394795e-06   -4.89718342050124e-06   -4.92508148640287e-06   -4.85676082430702e-06   -4.83794711619449e-06   -4.86294246280772e-06   -4.89460325754852e-06   -4.70802499026627e-06   -4.76382106350249e-06   -4.83284052123499e-06   -4.90298879405879e-06   -4.91798601239289e-06   -4.85235303418556e-06   -4.87261808551720e-06   -4.76091841079235e-06   -4.79585815232190e-06   -4.86466258024554e-06   -4.86460882068290e-06   -4.78951523683887e-06   -4.75199532056575e-06   -4.71931322898312e-06   -4.79327798466120e-06   -4.71619551789174e-06   -4.80789892524642e-06   -4.68243834487953e-06   -4.68781369752333e-06   -4.72484981960907e-06   -4.74946890673868e-06   -4.66029190898965e-06   -4.52725210708961e-06   -4.49456999970155e-06   -4.54611956179680e-06 ]
prominence_factor_localp2p = 0.0000004;
figure;
subplot(2,1,1)
findpeaks (data,'MinPeakProminence', prominence_factor_localp2p);
subplot(2,1,2)
findpeaks (-data,'MinPeakProminence', prominence_factor_localp2p);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
[x,y] = ginput(1) % Returns x and y after one mouse click
```

if you want to get one peak or:

```
[X,Y] = ginput() % Returns X=[x1..xN] and Y=[y1..yN] after N clicks, stop with ENTER
```

if you want to get multiple peaks in vector format

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Unfortunately, I don't have the Signal Processing Toolbox (`findpeaks` is part of the SPT) so I'll answer this without it.</sub>

---

Say you have a function:

```
x = sin(linspace(0, 2*pi, 1000)) + 0.1*rand(1, 1000);
plot(linspace(0, 2*pi, 1000),x);
```

This gives be the following plot:

[image]

Now, using the function "Data Cursor" [image], 
you can select a point on the plot by clicking at it. You can drag the data tip around if you didn't hit the correct point at the first try. If you right click on the frame that comes up, you can export the `[x,y]` values to the workspace:

[image]

This gives the following variable (struct) in the workspace:

```
peak_value_1    
peak_value_1 = 
       Target: [1x1 Line]
     Position: [1.5849 1.0984]
    DataIndex: 253
```

Now you have the positions of the maximum point:

```
position = peak_value_1.Position    
position =    
    1.5849    1.0984
```

How you want to proceed from here is your call. Note that you can create multiple data tips by holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> button while clicking.

Comment: Great! Thank you Stewie , that helps a lot! Two questions: 1) Any way to make that 'programmatically' (from the code: automatically go into curser mode and export the variables into workspace)? 2) Any way to avoid the datatips coming up (because they are hiding the whole plot and then it is hard to select the other points)?

Comment: I found a function on FileExchange that did the trick: [selectdata.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13857-graphical-data-selection-tool/content/selectdata.m) . Thanks for your help!